IIS Rewrite Rule to serve Index.html for React app
Here is my rule to set up rewrite rules to serve a React app's index.html file and it is not working for me, here is the url input http://mypage.com/Error/NotFound?aspxerrorpath=xxxxxxx, I am not sure what I am missing here and I put index.html at the root level. Thanks for the help.
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to React pages" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
            <condition>
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/Error/NotFound" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </condition>
            <action type="Redirect" url="/index.html" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>


You can try this rule:
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">   
  <match url="(.*)" />  
    <conditions>  
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mypage.com" />  
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)" />  
    </conditions>  
  <action type="Redirect" url="/index.html" />  
</rule>  


Rewrite instead of Redirect: The action type is set to Rewrite, which ensures the content of index.html is served without changing the URL in the browser.
Match URL Condition: The match URL pattern is set to .* to match all URLs.
Placement of index.html:
Make sure the index.html file is correctly placed at the root level of your web server.
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to React index.html" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/Error/NotFound" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>

I hope this will work.
